# sending 'A' character by using bitbanging method

Tags: serial-port, microcontroller, pic

i am trying to send 'A' character by using bitbanging method. Can anyone help me to write this code in send_serial() function

```
void send_serial()
{
//send data 

}

void main()
{

   setup_adc_ports(NO_ANALOGS|VSS_VDD);
   setup_adc(ADC_CLOCK_DIV_2);
   setup_timer_0(RTCC_INTERNAL|RTCC_DIV_1);
   setup_timer_1(T1_DISABLED);
   setup_timer_2(T2_DISABLED,0,1);
   setup_ccp1(CCP_OFF);
   setup_comparator(NC_NC_NC_NC);// This device COMP currently not supported by the PICWizard
//Setup_Oscillator parameter not selected from Intr Oscillator Config tab


   //!!!!!!!!!!!deney!!!!!!!!!!!!!
   //c6 pin using for data transfer
   //config tris
   //set_tris_c(??)



   while(1)
   {
      //'A' on ascii 0x41
      send_serial();
      delay_ms(1000);

   }

}
```

Comment: Which output bit should be driven?

Comment: Sounds unpleasant. You really ought to figure out what your output waveform will look like. Everything from there should be straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

This is fully described in Microchip's [Application Note AN510](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=1824&appnote=en010973) for PICs without a built in UART. However, if you can change to one which has a UART you would find the code much easier and it eases the timing restriction since the bits are sent by the hardware. The description of how to use a built in UART is described in the PIC datasheet or [AN774](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=1824&appnote=en012073).